# unable to understand guarantee of fork()

Tags: c, unix, fork

I'm unable to understand whether there is a guarantee about arising after `fork()`. While studying on *chain process* and *fan process*, I'm stuck. If I fork two times, the hierarchy is roughly

[image]

They are conditions of the codes:

- `(childpid = fork()) <= 0` if child or error, break it. (fan)
- `(childpid = fork()) > 0` if parent, break it. (chain)

For fan of 2 processes, shown that sketch

[image]

For chain of 2 processes, shown that sketch

[image]

So my stacking point is here that how it can be known which parent will break? Is there a guarantee first parent's(top 1) fork will be created firstly, then the other parent's(left 1) will be created secondly? For example can the sketch be possible for fan situation? Why? **If yes, in chain for 2 calls fork(), 3 processes are created. Who is the third? As far as I check, it is grandchild. But in this respect and in this situation grandchild is created before grandparent's child.**

[image]

*simplechain.c*

```
/* UNIX Systems Programming: Communication, Concurrency and Threads 2nd 
   Edition, Kay Robbins and Steven Robbins */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pid_t childpid = 0;
   int i, n;

   n = 2;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (childpid = fork())
         break;

   fprintf(stderr, "i:%d  process ID:%ld  parent ID:%ld  child ID:%ld\n",
           i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
   return 0;
}
```

*simplefan.c*

```
/* UNIX Systems Programming: Communication, Concurrency and Threads 2nd 
   Edition, Kay Robbins and Steven Robbins */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pid_t childpid = 0;
   int i, n;

   n = 2;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if ((childpid = fork()) <= 0)
         break;

   fprintf(stderr, "i:%d  process ID:%ld  parent ID:%ld  child ID:%ld\n",
           i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is *difficult to understand* (and to explain). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on *existing* programs. Read the source code of some free software shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a guarantee first parent's(top 1) fork will be created firstly, then the other parent's(left 1) will be created secondly? For example can the sketch be possible for fan situation? Why?

The first parent's child **is the parent** of the second one, so there is a guarantee. It is as certain as is that my grandmother gave birth to my mother before I was born.

There are 3 processes in total. One `fork()` call has one original process and it creates one child process.

The original process calls `fork()`; `fork()` returns non-zero child pid in parent so the `for` loop is broken. It returns 0 in child, which means the loop continues, and evaluates now for `i = 1`. `fork()` is called again and the same thing happens: the `for` loop is exited by break. In child process, after `i++`, `i < n` is false and the loop is exited. In total `fork()` was called twice. There have been 3 processes: the original process, its child and its grandchild. The code created **2** of those 3.

Comment: 'as certain as is that my grandmother gave birth to my mother before I was born' - oh dear, with my family tree, that would be bad:)

Comment: in chain for 2 calls fork(), 3 processes are created. Who is the third? As far as I check, it is grandchild. But in this respect and in this situation grandchild is created before grandparent's child.

Comment: @snr Yes, one can be older than one's uncle. So what's the question here? In the program you show, there is no guarantee that all children will be created before all grandchildren. To have such a guarantee, one must implement it explicitly.